# comparison operator for user object in priority queue

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I have following problem description

You have a program which is parallelized and uses "n" independent threads to process the given list of "m"
jobs. Threads take jobs in the order they are given in the input. If there is a free thread, it immediately
takes the next job from the list. If a thread has started processing a job, it doesn’t interrupt or stop
until it finishes processing the job. If several threads try to take jobs from the list simultaneously, the
thread with smaller index takes the job. For each job you know exactly how long will it take any thread
to process this job, and this time is the same for all the threads. You need to determine for each job
which thread will process it and when will it start processing.

Input Format. The first line of the input contains integers "n" and "m"
The second line contains  integers  — the times in seconds it takes any thread to process -th job.
The times are given in the same order as they are in the list from which threads take jobs.
Threads are indexed starting from 0.

If I have following input

```
4 20
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

For above code I have following code

```
struct qThreadDetails {
        std::uint64_t m_uiThreadId;
        std::uint64_t m_availableTime;
        std::uint64_t m_counter;
};

struct qThreadCompare {
    bool operator()(const qThreadDetails & lhs, const qThreadDetails & rhs) const {
        if(lhs.m_availableTime < rhs.m_availableTime ) {
            if (lhs.m_uiThreadId < rhs.m_uiThreadId) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (lhs.m_availableTime < rhs.m_availableTime ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

std::priority_queue<qThreadDetails, std::vector<qThreadDetails>, qThreadCompare > m_queThreads;

if (m_vecJobTimes.size() > 0) {
    m_vecAssignedWorkers.push_back(0);
    m_vecStartTimes.push_back(0);
    qThreadDetails jobDetails;
    // push job in queue.
    jobDetails.m_uiThreadId = 0;
    jobDetails.m_availableTime = m_vecJobTimes[0];
    jobDetails.m_counter = 0;
    m_queThreads.push(jobDetails);
}

unsigned int uiVecStartTimesIdx = 1;
for(unsigned int i = 1; i < m_uiNoOfThreads && uiVecStartTimesIdx < m_vecJobTimes.size(); 
                        ++i, uiVecStartTimesIdx++) {

    m_vecAssignedWorkers.push_back(i);
    m_vecStartTimes.push_back(0);
    // push jobs in queue.
    qThreadDetails jobDetails;
    jobDetails.m_uiThreadId = i;
    jobDetails.m_counter = 0;
    jobDetails.m_availableTime = m_vecJobTimes[i];

    m_queThreads.push(jobDetails); // ---------> problem here
}
```

It is crashing invalid operator < . not sure why. For input given above. Any help

Comment: Something that's vaguely described as "invalid operator <" is not a crash, but a compilation error. Additionally, your comparison operator appears to be fundamentally broken. The first `if` statement can be completely removed because it is redundant. Finally, the shown code, overall, fails to meet the requirements of a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's center. You need to edit your question and reorganize the shown code a single chunk that is ***complete*** and that anyone can attempt to compile in order to reproduce your compilation error. As is, this question is unclear.

Comment: `qThreadCompare` doesn't satisfy the requirements of [a strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). It's obviously not irreflexive: `qThreadCompare(x, x) == true` for any `x`. Attempting to use it as a comparator for `std::priority_queue` therefore exhibits undefined behavior.